# Everything is 64-bit yet Visual Studio still shows Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 not registered error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, ms-access-2010

**Setup:**

- Windows 7 64-bit
- Office 2010 Professional 64-bit
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional

---

Using Connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=c:\\testdb.accb;
```

I get the following error:

> 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

The provider/driver is working fine within Office 2010.

I can link to the database from inside Excel and the connection properties shows

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
User ID=Admin;
Data Source=C:\TestDB.accdb;
Mode=Share Deny Write;
ExtendedProperties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database="";
Jet OLEDB:RegistryPath="";
Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;
Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;
Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:CreateSystem Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;
Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;
Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False
```

I have been Googling  this for the last 3 days and can get nowhere, most of the solutions out there are based on the problem arising when trying to connect to Office 2007 or Office 2010 32 bit, but everything on my system is 64-bit.

Even though I thought none of them relevant, I did try the usual recommended solutions of installing AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 and setting my VS project build to x86 instead of Any CPU but none of it made any difference.

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Comment: 64-bit is `x64`, not `x86`, so you should change `Any CPU` to `x64` if anything. Also, what is your project type?

Comment: Tried x64 but no difference. Project type doesn't seem to matter, I'm using this in Asp.net but I've also tried it in a test project using Windows Forms, get exact same error.

Comment: What web server are you using? The VS default "Cassini" does not support 64-bit as far as I know.

Comment: I'm testing the website using Cassini but tried it in IIS 7.5, same error.

Comment: Did you use a 64-bit application pool in IIS? Also, I had the same problem even in 64-bit until I rebooted my computer after install, it's not in the installation instructions so thought you might not have done it.

Comment: Enable 32 bit Applications was set to true, I've changed that to false and rebooted. Now when I run the site in IIS 7.5, the error message changes to "Could not find installable ISAM". Still getting original error when running in Cassini or using Windows Form app.

Comment: Try changing your "DataSource" to "Data Source" in the connection string and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Error message changes to "Could not find file 'path'.

Comment: You have to put double quotes around the Data Source path string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually found an answer to this [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/office2007deploymentcompatibility/thread/cc10d906-0fd8-49ef-a1b0-45814bd70c55), I had to install the [2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Component](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)s as well as Office 2010; I haven't a clue why I should have to that but it works!

Comment: Joachim and Hans were right, by the way, the connection string needs to be set to Data Source with path in quotes if it contains spaces.